# Creation time of a lock in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, locking

So I'm trying to monitor the longest living lock in my database. The idea is that if a lock has been held for a certain amount of time, I will receive a warning in my application.

But for the life of I can't find the creation time of the locks.

I have used:

```
exec msdb..sp_lock
exec msdb..sp_who2
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
select * from sys.syslockinfo
select cmd, * from sys.sysprocesses where blocked > 0
```

But none of these seem to have the information I need.

Any ideas?

G

Answer (score 0):

A long running transaction makes more sense which you can do by looking at `database_transaction_begin_time` column in [`sys.dm_tran_database_transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186957.aspx)

I've never known anyone to try and monitor locks... which is possibly why there is no start date/time information for them...

Comment: Thanks but some of these transactions take very long so I don't think I can use this. But I'm beginning to think you're right about this never being monitored, I can't seem to find anything about this anywhere.

Comment: Is that the only possible explanation? The application I'm working on monitors a lot of large databases and I don't want to be getting warnings 24/7 on transactions that are all right.

Comment: For a long running transaction. There is no current problem. What I'm trying to implement is a monitoring application. I had an idea that if an exclusive lock had been held for a certain amount of time it would issue a warning to me via email. Sorry if I'm not making myself clear.

Comment: Isn't your logic the wrong way round? "I've never seen alligators in Boston, which is why there aren't any alligators in Boston"?

Comment: @Kerrek SB. Maybe. What would you suggest? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: @Gisli: Well, just the opposite inference: "I've never seen alligators **because** there aren't any."

Comment: @Kerrek SB . What? Please explain what you mean.

Comment: @Gisli: This is getting way off-topic. I merely commented on how gbn's argument was that the **reason** for not having timing information for locks is **because he never saw one**, whereas the logic should be the other way round. This has nothing to do with your actual problem, I'm afraid, and I have no idea whether this timing information even exists -- but monitoring transaction time does seem to be a far more idiomatic thing to do in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The Lock:Acquired EventClass in SQL Profiler has StartTime and EndTime. You might want to check that